# $n^2-2^m = 1$, cant find the answer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Hello today my teacher told us to find the solutions for $$n^2-2^m = 1$$ I came up with n= square root of 33 and m = 5, but after a review i saw that my calcultions were wrong ( i think ). could someone explain me if it was just a case or i did something right in my calculations ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Partial Differential Equations?

Comment: You calculated a correct pairing, but my guess is that $n,m$ are expected to be integers.  I would start with a smaller $n$ to begin with...

Comment: There's an obvious solution in integers, presumably this is what you were meant to look for.  There are infinitely many solutions if you don't require them to be integers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all answers of $n^2-2^m=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384400/find-all-answers-of-n2-2m-1) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%5E2-2%5Em%3D1%24&p=1). As [lulu's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4792335/n2-2m-1-cant-find-the-answer#comment10189680_4792335) indicates, this is assuming that $m$ and $n$ are integers since, otherwise, there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: A nice little fact to carry around is Mihailescu's theorem, which states that the only two perfect powers (greater than $1$) that differ by $1$ are $8,9$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rewrite that as $2^m = n^2 -1$ which is the same as $2^m = (n+1)\times(n-1)$

It immediately yields that both $n+1$ and $n-1$ are exact powers of 2. We can say that $\dfrac{n+1}{n-1}$ must be $2$: it cannot be 1 (would lead to $2 = 0$!), and any value strictly greater than 2 (4, 8, ...) would imply $n < 0$.

So the solution is given by:
$$\dfrac{n+1}{n-1}=2 \Leftrightarrow n+1 = 2n -2 \Leftrightarrow n=3$$

We can deduce immediately that $2^m = 3^2 -1 = 8$, so $m=3$.